# Why my Java method is not listed in CPU-Profiler in AndroidStudio3.5.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I am doing cpu-profiling using Android Studio3.5.1 using Android-Profiler using Sample Java Method option.When a non-optimised version of a method i use, method get listed in method trace pane. But when i try with optimised version of same method the method not getting listed in the pane.

Tried with two version of same method.

```
public int computeFibonacci(int positionInFibSequence) {
     int prev = 0;
     int current = 1;
     int newValue;
     for (int i=1; i<positionInFibSequence; i++) {
         newValue = current + prev;
         prev = current;
         current = newValue;
     }
     return current;

     /*if (positionInFibSequence <= 2) {
         return 1;
     } else {
         return computeFibonacci(positionInFibSequence - 1)
                 + computeFibonacci(positionInFibSequence - 2);
     }*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Updating here because someone may have similar issue.

> An inherent issue of sampled-based tracing is that if your app enters
>   a method after a capture of the call stack and exits the method before
>   the next capture, that method call is not logged by the profiler. If
>   you are interested in tracing methods with such short lifecycles, you
>   should use instrumented tracing.

[word of official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#configurations)

Thanks.

Happy Coding.